# Mocking PendingIntent instance and static within same test

Tags: android, junit, mockito, robolectric, powermockito

I cannot seem to figure this out. I get `java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class`

I'm trying to figure out how to send a pending intent, by pushing it into a class for organization. Currently I have the following:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(PendingIntent.class)
public class TheTests{
    private Context _context;
    private AlarmManager _alarmManager;
    private Manager _manager;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        _alarmManager = Mockito.mock(AlarmManager.class);
        _context = Mockito.mock(Context.class);
        Mockito.when(_context.getSystemService(anyString())).thenReturn(_alarmManager);
        _manager = new Manager(_context);
    }

    @Test
    public void example() {
        PendingIntent expected = PowerMockito.mock(PendingIntent.class);

        PowerMockito
                .when(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(any(Context.class), anyInt(), any(Intent.class), anyInt()))
                .thenReturn(expected);

        _manager.broadcast(_cal, new Schedule());
    }
}

public Manager class {
    public void broadcast(Thing thing) {
        if (thing == null) {
            return;
        }

        Intent sender = new Intent("broadcast.AlarmReceiverFilter");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, sender, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        _alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

After all of this, I cannot figure how to make them all play nicely. My goal is to verify what is called within `getBroadcast` and equally the `Intent` itself.

What's the approach I should take?

Thanks,
Kelly

Update: Talking below it was suggested to avoid powermock, so I tried the following:

```
@Test
public void example2() {
    ShadowApplication shadowApp = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application);

    _manager = new TimeManager(shadowApp.getApplicationContext());
    _manager.broadcast(new Thing());

    List<Intent> intents = shadowApp.getBroadcastIntents();
    assertEquals(intents.size(), 1); // actual size is 0 (zero)
}
```

Comment: can you paste your error trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use `PowerMock` here.

And just use:

```
ShadowApplication shadowApp = shadowOf(RuntimeEnvironment.application);
List<Intent> intents = shadowApp.getBroadcastIntents();
```

And then find your intent there.

UPD. I'm sorry, I didn't notice that you mocked `AlarmManager`. You should not do it and use:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)RuntimeEnvironment.application.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
ShadowAlarmManager shadowAlarmManager = shadowOf(alarmManager);
List<ShadowAlarmManager.ScheduledAlarm> alarms = shadowAlarmManager.getScheduledAlarms();
```

Comment: Hi Eugen, Thank you for the advice. It seems that I'm not getting any of the broadcast when I do that. I'll make an edit in the code above talking about your idea.

Comment: Updated answer with AlarmManager. I would advise to dive to some shadows from Robolectric.

Comment: That was perfect @Eugen. Thank you explaining it more to me. Equally thanks for helping me understand the potential (and casting) of `shadow` classes